# How do I get Clojure to load a project-specific .clj file on REPL launch?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How do I get Clojure to load a project-specific .clj file on repl launch?  I want to have some function available to me whenever I open up a new repl (I'm using nREPL on emacs, for what it's worth...)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an entry to your `project.clj`'s `:repl-options` like the following

```
:repl-options {:init (load-file "src/your-project-specific-file.clj") }
```

If you'd like your functions to be available in all your REPLs, add an entry the user profile in `.lein/profiles.clj` as follows:

```
{
 :user
  {:repl-options {:init (load-file "path/to/file.clj")}}
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `:user` instead of `:dev`. [The :user profile is separate from :dev; the latter is intended to be specified in the project itself. In order to avoid collisions, the project should never define a :user profile, nor should a user-wide :dev profile be defined.](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md)